# MVC validation: where to validate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We say that model validation at controllers layer is the correct place to validate all data we gonna operate with. In this case, if we change UI to another (remembering that our layers must be pretty decoupled) the new data validation principles are going to execute - in this case all our inner rules can be violated.
You may say that data models is the separate layer and that layer, but not UI, is the only place for validation. But in this case i found it more effective to validate data in the service or business objects layer, don't i?
In fact we have a number of objects corresponding to our domain object: db table record, linq2sql class, domain object class, viewmodel class. Should it be only one place to validate data model? Why should it be in (or close to) UI but not in the other layer? In my opinion, the validation must occur in the service layer - with all other busness logic. If i need to inform user about error as fast as possible, i'll use client validation in addition to main one. Thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data validation is the responsibility of the model. The best place to put validation rules in my opinion is as constraints in the database. Having constraints ensures that no incorrect data will ever be stored in the database, no matter how it is access. Unfortunately only basic constraints are suitable to express in the database.

The next place to put validation, when using linq-to-sql for data access, I is the extension methods on the entity classes. Then all code will have to pass through the validation.

To improve user experience, basic validation can be repeated in the UI, but that is just for user experience and to catch the most common mistakes early. On the web, using JavaScript validation is preferable. On rich clients the same code as the one called by the extension methods can sometimes be reused.

Always remember that any service exposed to a client, could be called by a malicious client that lacks the validation that the real client does. Never trust the client to do any kind of validation or security checks correctly.

Comment: I agree, validation, regardless of language/framework starts at the data access layer(mandatory), then the business layer(optional), and finally the presentation layer(optional). Although the last two may be optional I highly suggest validation is implemented.

Comment: So you use validation on several layers? Are you agree that all data model validation (usually made via annottions) can be implemented in service layer and client code?

Answer (score 1):

1.It is validated at UI level because to reduce the one extra hit to server. (EnableClientSideValidation check). And its for basic validations only(like invalid input etc)

2.Many business validations are written in Business layer where they intact irrespective to the UI(WPF or MVC)

3.Usually we write UI validation in controller and specific to MVC.

4.You should keep the validation part as per the prefrences. like sometime we validate entity for unique constraint in such case I would prefer to write my validation attribute over the Entity itself.So at the time of insertion to the database it will be validated.

Also you can try to introduce another layer(new library) here for simplicity and decoupling approach, 
This new layer will do, some validation which are not specific to UI and not specific to business logic. We will call it as App Services Layer which also actually helps you to interact with WCF like scenarios. So now your controller and WCF will interact with same layer and with same validation.

Comment: Should controller's validation be doubled in deeper layers? If not, what if i take another controller with another validation rules? This can voilate my business-layer logic.

Answer (score 0):

Data Validation should happen at the domain level. But UI validation errors should be caught without having to ask someone else downstream.

Comment: Do you mean that you have methods like Validate right in your business classes? UI vaidation can be mostly implemented in js/jquery

Comment: A better way would be to attach attributes to model classes. Keeps models cleaner, and let's you easily add client validation  See this blog post for an example: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx

Comment: thank you. I know how to use that attributes. I only cant understand why to use model validation if: 1) we can validate a lot on client 2) if query to the site is occured anyway i'd better validate my domain object which is passed into service methods Add, Edit etc. And also service layer validation is easier for testing than controller's one.

Comment: well u will want to validate on client as well, and there are several libraries which will help with this. but having it only there is less secure. also, javascript may be disabled